# linq limit and filter large set of result

Tags: asp.net, linq, filter

I have a large amount of data in the database. I want to filter the result and get a specific number of product

For example: the PageSize=100. i want to get 100 products on each page, and the product's description contains the string "Laptop"

```
Products = repository.Products
           .OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
           .Where(x=>x.Description.Contains("%Laptop%")
           .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
           .Take(PageSize);
```

This query timed out since the query filters a large result before retrieving the first 100 products

But if I write

```
Products = repository.Products
               .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
               .Take(PageSize)
               .OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
               .Where(x=>x.Description.Contains("%Laptop%");
```

Then page 1 doesn't have 100 products because the query retries 100 products first and then filtering

What should I do to retrieving 100 products (contain the string"Laptop") and not get time out error?

Comment: Are you sure it will timeout? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Where` first, order next, take afterwards.

Like this:

```
Products = repository.Products
               .Where(x=>x.Description.Contains("Laptop");
               .OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
               .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
               .Take(PageSize)
```

Note, contains get turned into `like %input%`, so no need to surround it with `%`s ;)

Comment: awesome! it works!!! can you explain the convention? I thought it did the filtering first so it would time out (but it didn't)

Comment: It's just so that you don't have to process extra elements unnecessarily.